# Remote desktop view (krfb / vnc) not updating on client

Tags: kde, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I am having a weird problem when running krfb (KDE remote desktop sharing). I can see the initial snapshot of the remote desktop after connecting, I can manipulate windows on the remote desktop with the mouse, but my view of the desktop does not change. It remains as the snapshot of the desktop from the moment I connected it. Basically, it seems that GUI updates are not correctly being transferred to the VNC client.

This is regardless of which VNC client software I uses (TightVNC, RealVNC, etc...) - the behavior is the same.

Any help would be immensely appreciated, because I am completely lost as to why GUI updates are not coming from the VNC server to the client.

Comment: I to have had this problem. I think it has something to do with the server because if I connect to an other server it is fine. can you reinstall / install a different server on the remote machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually suggest an alternate VNC server, x11vncserver or FreeNX.

[X11 manpage](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) and download

OR

FreeNX from the FreeNX Team PPA.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team`

NOTE: If you do not have add-apt-repository installed add the following

`sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

Update Apt

`sudo apt-get update`

Install FreeNX

`sudo apt-get install freenx`

[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX)

Comment: I had this problem using vino (ubuntu, gnome, compiz, etc.), and x11vnc seems to me the best-kept vnc secret! The options, the flexibility, the command-line client! I was a bit squeemish about installing a new vnc server, but now I'm enthusiastic! 5 + votes!!